# QT compile static + OpenSSL error

Tags: qt, ssl, static, compiler-errors

I have downloaded source files of qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0 from here: https://download.qt.io/snapshots/qt/5.8/5.8.0/latest_src/

I have installed QtFramework(qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw530-5.8.0) and Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2k downloaded from here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

I want to compile it with support for Static version of QT + OpenSSL

I tried the following configuration 
[image: cmd]
`configure -static -release -platform win32-g++ -openssl-linked -I C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include -L C:/OpenSSL-Win32 /lib` 
and then mingw32-make , but I bring the following error.

```
ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x691): undefined reference to SSL_library_init'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x6a1): undefined reference
     toSSL_load_error_strings' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x6b1): undefined reference to SSL_new'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x6c1): undefined reference
     toSSL_ctrl' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x6d1): undefined reference to SSL_read'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x6e1): undefined reference
     toSSL_set_bio' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x6f1): undefined reference to SSL_set_accept_state'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x701): undefined reference
     toSSL_set_connect_state' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x711): undefined reference to SSL_shutdown'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x721): undefined reference
     toSSL_set_session' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x731): undefined reference to SSL_SESSION_free'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x741): undefined reference
     toSSL_get1_session' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x751): undefined reference to SSL_get_session'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x761): undefined reference
     toSSL_get_ex_new_index' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x771): undefined reference to SSL_set_ex_data'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x781): undefined reference
     toSSL_get_ex_data' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x791): undefined reference to SSL_set_psk_client_callback'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x7a1): undefined reference
     toSSL_set_psk_server_callback' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x7b1): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_use_psk_identity_hint'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x7c1): undefined reference
     toSSLv3_client_method' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x7d1): undefined reference to SSLv23_client_method'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x7e1): undefined reference
     toTLSv1_client_method' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x7f1): undefined reference to TLSv1_1_client_method'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x801): undefined reference
     toTLSv1_2_client_method' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x811): undefined reference to SSLv3_server_method'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x821): undefined reference
     toSSLv23_server_method' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x831): undefined reference to TLSv1_server_method'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x841): undefined reference
     toTLSv1_1_server_method' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x851): undefined reference to TLSv1_2_server_method'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x861): undefined reference
     toSSL_write' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x871): undefined reference to X509_cmp'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x881): undefined reference
     toX509_dup' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x891): undefined reference to X509_print'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x8a1): undefined reference
     toX509_EXTENSION_get_object' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x8b1): undefined reference to X509_free'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x8c1): undefined reference
     toX509_get_ext' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x8d1): undefined reference to X509_get_ext_count'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x8e1): undefined reference
     toX509_get_ext_d2i' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x8f1): undefined reference to X509V3_EXT_get'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x901): undefined reference
     toX509V3_EXT_d2i' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x911): undefined reference to X509_EXTENSION_get_critical'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x921): undefined reference
     toX509_EXTENSION_get_data' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x931): undefined reference to BASIC_CONSTRAINTS_free'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x941): undefined reference
     toAUTHORITY_KEYID_free' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x951): undefined reference to ASN1_STRING_print'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x961): undefined reference
     toX509_check_issued' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x971): undefined reference to X509_get_issuer_name'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x981): undefined reference
     toX509_get_subject_name' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x991): undefined reference to X509_verify_cert'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x9a1): undefined reference
     toX509_NAME_entry_count' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x9b1): undefined reference to X509_NAME_get_entry'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x9c1): undefined reference
     toX509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x9d1): undefined reference to X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_object'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x9e1): undefined reference
     toX509_PUBKEY_get' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x9f1): undefined reference to X509_STORE_free'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xa01): undefined reference
     toX509_STORE_new' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xa11): undefined reference to X509_STORE_add_cert'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xa21): undefined reference
     toX509_STORE_CTX_free' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xa31): undefined reference to X509_STORE_CTX_init'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xa41): undefined reference
     toX509_STORE_CTX_set_purpose' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xa51): undefined reference to X509_STORE_CTX_get_error'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xa61): undefined reference
     toX509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xa71): undefined reference to X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xa81): undefined reference
     toX509_STORE_CTX_get_chain' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xa91): undefined reference to X509_STORE_CTX_new'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xaa1): undefined reference
     toOPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xab1): undefined reference to OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xac1): undefined reference
     toSSL_CTX_load_verify_locations' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xad1): undefined reference to SSLeay'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xae1): undefined reference
     toSSLeay_version' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xaf1): undefined reference to i2d_SSL_SESSION'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xb01): undefined reference
     tod2i_SSL_SESSION' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xb11): undefined reference to SSL_select_next_proto'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xb21): undefined reference
     toSSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xb31): undefined reference to SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xb41): undefined reference
     toSSL_set_alpn_protos' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xb51): undefined reference to SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xb61): undefined reference
     toSSL_get0_alpn_selected' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xb71): undefined reference to DH_new'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xb81): undefined reference
     toDH_free' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xb91): undefined reference to d2i_DHparams'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xba1): undefined reference
     toi2d_DHparams' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xbb1): undefined reference to DH_check'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xbc1): undefined reference
     toBN_bin2bn' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xbd1): undefined reference to EC_KEY_dup'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xbe1): undefined reference
     toEC_KEY_new_by_curve_name' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xbf1): undefined reference to EC_KEY_free'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xc01): undefined reference
     toEC_get_builtin_curves' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xc11): undefined reference to EC_curve_nist2nid'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xc21): undefined reference
     toPKCS12_parse' C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xc31): undefined reference to d2i_PKCS12_bio'
    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_open
    ssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0xc41): undefined reference
     toPKCS12_free' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status Makefile.Release:62: recipe for target 'release\download.exe' failed mingw32-make[5]: * [release\download.exe] Error 1 mingw32-make[5]: Leaving directory 'C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase /examples/network/download' Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed mingw32-make[4]: [release] Error 2 mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory 'C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase /examples/network/download' Makefile:56: recipe for target 'sub-download-make_first' failed mingw32-make[3]: [sub-download-make_first] Error 2 mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase /examples/network' Makefile:150: recipe for target 'sub-network-make_first' failed mingw32-make[2]: [sub-network-make_first] Error 2 mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase /examples' Makefile:67: recipe for target 'sub-examples-make_first' failed mingw32-make[1]: [sub-examples-make_first] Error 2 mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase ' Makefile:75: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed mingw32-make: * [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2

C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0>
```

I tried also 
`configure -static -release -platform win32-g++ -openssl-linked -I C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include -L C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib OPENSSL_LIBS="-llibeay32 -lssleay32 -lgdi32"`

[image: error]

Comment: `-L C:/OpenSSL-Win32 /lib` is this a typo or there is a space before `/lib`?

Comment: @Paul is a typo

Comment: Could you show the contents of `C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib`?

Comment: @Paul Yes https://s27.postimg.org/pzln2qd7n/cong.jpg

Comment: If you are using MinGW, maybe you should try `-L C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/MinGW/`. I'm just guessing, I never used that installer and always built OpenSSL from sources.

Comment: @Paul I tried the following configuration:
`configure -static -release -platform win32-g ++ -openssl -I C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -L c:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\MinGW` 
The time during which flowed compilation was much longer (perhaps to 6:00) and everything was fine until we reached the QtSpeech [error img](https://s28.postimg.org/d2afyr9nh/image.jpg) 
If you can share what compiler and configuration you use